# textContent works on a node, but innerText does not?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I currently have following code:

```
  function wrapTextNodeInWordTags(textNode) {
  if (
    textNode.nodeName !== "#text" ||
    textNode.parentNode.nodeName === "SCRIPT" ||
    textNode.parentNode.nodeName === "STYLE" ||
    textNode.parentNode.nodeName === "IFRAME"
  ) {
    return;
  }
  let origText = textNode.textContent; --> the issue
  let newHtml = wrapWords(origText);

  if (newHtml !== origText) {
    let newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    newSpan.innerHTML = newHtml;
    textNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newSpan, textNode);
  }
}

function wrapDOM() {
  let all = document.querySelectorAll("*");
  let textNodes = [];
  for (let p of all) {
    let nodeIter = document.createNodeIterator(p, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    let currentNode;

    while ((currentNode = nodeIter.nextNode())) {
      textNodes.push(currentNode);
    }
  }

  textNodes.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.parentNode !== null) wrapTextNodeInWordTags(el);
  });

  iterWordTags();
}
```

It wraps all words on the page and does it so in a correct fashion... BUT `textNode.textContent` will extract all the text from the page, including those hidden in modals or other one-page wonders. If I replace it with `innerText`, which does exactly what I want (see: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) under differences from innerText) however, the node will return a whole bunch of `undefined`, sometimes a `-`
I'm a little confused when it comes to these nodes. What would be the reason this doesn't work ? Doing `body.innerText` works just fine, that's a node too, no ? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT 1:** I made a jsfiddle that illustrates what happens on a simple site with both innerText and textContent

https://jsfiddle.net/7jweed7y/6/

```js
function wrapTextNodeInWordTags(textNode) {

  document.getElementById('innerText-result').innerText += textNode.innerText;
  document.getElementById('textContent-result').innerText += textNode.textContent;
}

//Pick up all the tags on a page, seek their deepest node and perform the wrapping so that the text has elements to navigate to.
function wrapDOM() {
  let all = document.querySelectorAll("*");
  let textNodes = [];
  for (let p of all) {
    let nodeIter = document.createNodeIterator(p, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    let currentNode;

    while ((currentNode = nodeIter.nextNode())) {
      textNodes.push(currentNode);
    }
  }

  textNodes.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.parentNode !== null) wrapTextNodeInWordTags(el);
  });
}

document.getElementById('wrapDOM').addEventListener( 'click', function () {
wrapDOM();
});
```

```html
<h1>A. title</h1>
<div>
    Het museum werd ontworpen door architect Cor van Hillo!
    De totale kosten van 3,5 miljoen gulden werden door sponsors en fondsen bijeen gebracht.
    Onder andere door ANWB-leden werd 400.000 gulden gedoneerd.
    In 1992 werd begonnen met de bouw van het museum dat mede werd ingericht door het Haagse Museon.
    Op 9 maart 1993 opende prins Claus het museum door zich met een vuistbijl de toegang te verschaffen.

    <div>
        Het museum vertelt het geologische verhaal van de Veluwe en laat zien welke natuurlijke processen zich net en
        ver onder het aardoppervlak afspelen.
        Centraal in het Museonder hangt het wortelstelsel van een 135 jaar oude boom.
        Hiermee wordt het feit dat men zich onder het aardoppervlak bevindt extra versterkt.
    </div>

    In september 2017 werd bekend dat het plein waar nu het bezoekerscentrum en restaurant "De Koperen Kop" aan liggen
    zal worden gerenoveerd.
    Er komt een nieuw gebouw met de naam "Het Landhuis". Hier worden het bezoekers- en educatiecentrum, het restaurant
    en een parkwinkel ondergebracht.
    Door het verplaatsen van het bezoekerscentrum kan het Museonder worden vergroot en de collectie worden uitgebreid.
</div>

<h2>A subtitle</h2>
<div>Some more text underneath a title</div>

<button id='wrapDOM'>wrap the dom</button>

innerText Result:
<div id='innerText-result'>

</div>
textContent Result:
<div id='textContent-result'>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you produce an [MCVE] ?

Comment: Was working on that, it's there now. :)

Comment: Indeed that's sound strange, but I don't know innerText property that well. Anyway, here is a workaround which should basically do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/7jweed7y/7/

Comment: Looks good, did some tweaks to fit in the project and does what I expected it to do if innerText actually worked. You can drop it as an answer and I'll accept. :)